# Regular expression including leading space in word search

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regular expression:

```
((^|[^a-zA-ZäöåüßÄÖÅÜ])'+targetword+'(?![a-zA-ZäöåüßÄÖÅÜ]))(?![^<]*(?:<\/script|>))
```

I am using it to find the `targetword` and make a link out of it, but only when the word is not a part of another word.

EDIT: The regular expression is used in JavaScript, in RegExp object.

In other words, `'the'` would be linked, but `o'the'r` or `'the'apy` would not be.

The problem is that the above expression also includes the leading space in the link. So `'the'` becomes `' the'` in the link text.

I have found some solutions to finding and excluding leading spaces in this very site, but I have yet to find a way to embed them into the above expression as regular expressions really are not my forte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically you just need to define whitespaces to be not part of your match group:

```
(?:(?:^|[^a-zA-ZäöåüßÄÖÅÜ])\s*(targetword)(?![a-zA-ZäöåüßÄÖÅÜ]))(?![^<]*(?:<\/script|>))
```

should to the trick (Note the MATCHED, but EXCLUDED whitespace(s) in front of `targetword`)
Replace targetword with your variable of course.

Comment: I implemented this solution.
This regex combined with my linking function actually stripped the leading space entirely but I managed to resolve this by adding the space on the link creation function.

Answer (score 1):

This regex is not exactly the same as what you seems to be looking for, but it might work even better.

```
"\b" + targetword + "\b"
```

The \b's means that the word is should stand alone.
This also includes symbols, spaces, and digits.

If this was not what you were looking for, sorry for your inconvenience.

Comment: That's not going to work.  JavaScript's `\b` doesn't recognize accented letters like `ö` and `å` as word characters.  So if you try to match (for example) `\bfoö\b`, it will fail because the position after the `ö` isn't a word boundary.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `"\b" + targetword + "\b"` and this will work for most cases however this will match the word `donald` and in the string `O'Donald`  or match `Sarah` in the string `Sarah's car is broken`.

I would use look behinds and look aheads to validate

- the preceding character is a space, start of string, or acceptable punctuation
- the trailing character is a space, end of string, or acceptable punctuation

These allowed characters could be tailored to your actual use case.

`"(?<=[\s",.]|^)" + targetword + "(?=[\s",.\r\n]|$)"`

[image]

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\s",.]                  any character of: whitespace (\n, \r,
                             \t, \f, and " "), '"', ',', '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  targetword               'targetword'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\s",.\r\n]              any character of: whitespace (\n, \r,
                             \t, \f, and " "), '"', ',', '.', '\r'
                             (carriage return), '\n' (newline)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: The OP hasn't said which regex flavor he's using, but I'm pretty sure it's JavaScript, which doesn't support lookbehinds.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. Apologies for the omission of the JavaScript from the question, as @Alan Moore noted, especially if this renders the solution non-viable.